# docker journald logging driver cause huge amount of logging also to /var/log/syslog and /var/log/kern.log

Tags: linux, docker, logging, kubernetes, systemd

I currently configured the logging_driver of deamon docker to write to journald, in order to parse them with fluentd from a kubernetes pod. On the node side, i have a rsyslog running with the following default configuration:

```
#  Default rules for rsyslog.
#
#           For more information see rsyslog.conf(5) and /etc/rsyslog.conf

#
# First some standard log files.  Log by facility.
#
auth,authpriv.*         /var/log/auth.log
*.*;auth,authpriv.none      -/var/log/syslog
#cron.*             /var/log/cron.log
#daemon.*           -/var/log/daemon.log
kern.*              -/var/log/kern.log
#lpr.*              -/var/log/lpr.log
mail.*              -/var/log/mail.log
#user.*             -/var/log/user.log

#
# Logging for the mail system.  Split it up so that
# it is easy to write scripts to parse these files.
#
#mail.info          -/var/log/mail.info
#mail.warn          -/var/log/mail.warn
mail.err            /var/log/mail.err

#
# Logging for INN news system.
#
news.crit           /var/log/news/news.crit
news.err            /var/log/news/news.err
news.notice         -/var/log/news/news.notice

#
# Some "catch-all" log files.
#
#*.=debug;\
#   auth,authpriv.none;\
#   news.none;mail.none -/var/log/debug
#*.=info;*.=notice;*.=warn;\
#   auth,authpriv.none;\
#   cron,daemon.none;\
#   mail,news.none      -/var/log/messages

#
# Emergencies are sent to everybody logged in.
#
*.emerg                                :omusrmsg:*

#
# I like to have messages displayed on the console, but only on a virtual
# console I usually leave idle.
#
#daemon,mail.*;\
#   news.=crit;news.=err;news.=notice;\
#   *.=debug;*.=info;\
#   *.=notice;*.=warn   /dev/tty8

# The named pipe /dev/xconsole is for the `xconsole' utility.  To use it,
# you must invoke `xconsole' with the `-file' option:
#
#    $ xconsole -file /dev/xconsole [...]
#
# NOTE: adjust the list below, or you'll go crazy if you have a reasonably
#      busy site..
#
daemon.*;mail.*;\
    news.err;\
    *.=debug;*.=info;\
    *.=notice;*.=warn   |/dev/xconsole
```

What is happening is that all the logging that goes to journal is also put in the syslog and kern.log as well. 
Due to a great amount of container running inside kubernetes nodes and control plane, i would like to minimize the exponential logging in several locations, on top of the fact that putting them to journal, are already saved into EFK logging system. 
Does anyone is experiencing the same problem?, how i can avoid this?

Comment: Could you share configuration for your Docker daemon?

Comment: i pass flags to the startup wrapper using OPTIONS:
  `OPTIONS=" -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock --ip-forward=true --iptables=false --ip-masq=false --log-driver journald"`

Comment: Could you try to change settings in `/etc/docker/daemon.json` like in this instruction: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/json-file/

Comment: changing the log driver to json-file, the problem no more exists. Is not properly a solution, but eventually this is a workaround to avoid a great amount of duplicated space. Thanks a lot @ArtemGolenyaev

Answer (score 5):

By default, journald forwards logs to syslog.

You can turn it off by editing `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` and setting:

```
ForwardToSyslog=no
```

Then restart the service:

```
systemctl restart systemd-journald
```